# MATLAB GUI Updating plot

Tags: matlab, user-interface, plot

I have a MATLAB gui that demonstrates the plotting of real-time incoming data signal and a horizontal threshold line:

```
axes(handles.axes1);
plot([1 windowLength].*1/sampleFreq, [-data1Threshold -data1Threshold],'k','linewidth',2);
% Plotting the threshold line
xlim([1 windowLength].*1/sampleFreq);
ylim([-300 300]);
xlabel('Time (s)')
ylabel('Filtered signal (uV)')
hold on;
plot([1:10:length(data1)].*1/sampleFreq, data1(1:10:end),'b','linewidth',2);
% Plotting the signal over the threshold line
hold off;
drawnow;
```

This part of the code is inside a while loop so that different parts  of the signal (incoming signal) is plotted while the threshold line is identical.
The issue is that the gui runs really slow. Is there anyway I can fix the threshold line and the axis information, so that I can only update the incoming signal in order to improve the speed?

I have tried the following to fix the handles to the plot, however, this still requires me to plot the threshold line and the signal at every iteration... (also not sure how to use set function with multiple data lines to plot, the threshold line and signal)

```
handles.plot1 = plot([1 windowLength].*1/sampleFreq, [-data1Threshold -data1Threshold],'k',[1:1:length(data1)].*1/sampleFreq, data1,'b','linewidth',2);
set(handles.plot1,'xdata',[1:10:length(data1)].*1/sampleFreq, 'ydata',data1(1:10:end));
```

any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how much it would speed up the plotting, or if that would be the slow part, but I would definitely move the axis setup and the stationary portions of the plot outside of the while loop.  Then use a handle to the plot to update it (along the lines of where you are going with the `set` function).

I find it easier to actually just [delete](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/handle.delete.html) the particular plot line out of the figure, and then plot the new one:
Something like:

```
% Outside while loop:
axes(handles.axes1);
plot([1 windowLength].*1/sampleFreq, [-data1Threshold - data1Threshold],'k','linewidth',2);
% Plotting the threshold line
xlim([1 windowLength].*1/sampleFreq);
ylim([-300 300]);
xlabel('Time (s)')
ylabel('Filtered signal (uV)')
hold on;
... Other setup....

while(...)

  ... Lots of stuff ...

  if exist(handles.plot1)
    delete(handles.plot1);
  end
  handles.plot1 = plot(...New stuff here...);
  drawnow;

  ... Lots more stuff ...

end % while loop
```

I've used this before in running a simulation and it worked very well.

Comment: So exist('handles.plot1') works. However, handle.plot1 =plot(...); does work, but exist('handles.plot1') seems to always return 0.. I don't understand why..

Comment: You can always save it to a different variable, instead of the `handles` struct. I just thought it might be convenient to keep it with the other handles...